# Spring Security authentication using custom tables not working

Tags: spring-security

I am using spring security for authentication, but when i use database instead of hard coding users in userservice in my security-config.xml file it doesn't work.

here is authentication provider which i have configured.

I am using PostgreSQL DB. 
`<authentication-provider>
            <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource" 
                users-by-username-query="select * from (select name as username, password, enabled from ss_tbluser) where username = ?"
                authorities-by-username-query="select * from (select u.name as username, r.description as rolename from ss_user_roles as user_role
                join ss_tbluser as u on u.cid = user_role.userid
                join ss_tblroles as r on r.cid = user_role.roleid ) 
                where username = ?"/>
        </authentication-provider>`
 
and i am getting this error when i login with user that is present in table even.
Dec 19, 2014 7:17:47 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [org/springframework/jdbc/support/sql-error-codes.xml]
Dec 19, 2014 7:17:47 PM org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory 
INFO: SQLErrorCodes loaded: [DB2, Derby, H2, HSQL, Informix, MS-SQL, MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, Sybase]

Comment: I don't see the error.

Comment: Could you provide your dataSource configuration?

Comment: Do those queries work when you run them directly in postgres with username hardcoded into the query, instead of as a parameter? What do they return?

Comment: What are the sql types of the columns being queries?